# rails 4 post multiple child objects under multiple parent objects on the same form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have nested resources with a parent model called main and a child model called temperature. Each main can have many temperatures (1 to many). Is there any way to post multiple temperatures, with each temperature going to a different main object, on one single form using form_for and fields_for (I would like to have just one submit button)? The following is my main's index view and main & temperature controllers. Thanks!

```
<% @mains.each do |main| %>
<tr>
  <td>stuff.....</td>
  <td><%= form_for main do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :temperature do |t| %>
      temp: <%= t.text_field :temp %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %></td>
</tr>
```

```
class MainsController < ApplicationController
#stuff

def index
    @mains = Main.all
end

private 
    def main_params
        params.require(:main).permit(:freezer_id, :freezer_name, temperatures_attributes: [:id, :main_id, :temp, :date])
    end
end

class TemperaturesController < ApplicationController
#stuff
def create
    @main = Main.find(params[:main_id])
    logger.debug 'testing 1'
    @temp = @main.temperatures.create(temperature_params)
    if @temp.save
        redirect_to main_path(@main)
    else
        render 'mains/show'
    end

end


private
    def temperature_params
        params.require(:temperature).permit(:temp, :date)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is a bulk update/create on the database for diferent mains. Rails can't handle this on his convention as long as the require(param) is acting. You will need to create a bulk handler in the controller to create individual hashes from each entitiy in the array and then create a handler for the response of each model validations.
Not easy to do, but possible. 
Some references, for APIS, nothing for forms, but as long as the view create the appropiate hash, you can reuse it.

http://www.l1ghtm4n.com/post/53259404576/patterns-for-rest-api-bulk-operations

https://github.com/arsduo/batch_api

http://forrst.com/posts/Run_any_rails_RESTful_action_more_than_once_bul-Yb5